# cakephp 3.x Model adapter for 2.x

Tags: cakephp, model, upgrade

Is there somewhere [an adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for cakephp 3.x model to handle [2.x syntax](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)? Like, internally, it just convert syntax like this:

```
array(
    'conditions' => array('Model.field' => $thisValue),
    'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),
    'order' => array('Model.created', 'Model.field3 DESC'),
    'group' => array('Model.field'), 
    'limit' => n
)
```

into:

```
$query->select('Model.field1')
->distinct('Model.field2')
->order->(['Model.created', 'Model.field3' => 'DESC'])
->group('Model.field')
->where('Model.field' => $thisValue)
```

and return executed query ->toArray(). So the model of 2.x, becomes compatible with 3.x.

Many thanks to any advises.

Comment: Please note that questions asking for possible offsite ressources are considered offtopic on StackOverflow. You're better off asking such questions in the [**CakePHP forums**](http://discourse.cakephp.org/) or on [**IRC**](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=cakephp)/[**Slack**](http://cakesf.herokuapp.com/). SO is the place to ask for specific programming related problems that you have with converting syntax A to syntax B.

Comment: Yep, thank you. Asked [there](http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/compatibility-adapter-for-model-2-x-to-becomes-compatible-with-3-x-orm/1616) as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cake 3 you are not limited to query builder, you can also pass an array to `find()` (similar to how it worked in 2.x):

```
$query = $articles->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')],
    'contain' => ['Authors', 'Comments'],
    'limit' => 10
]);
```

You can read about it [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else facing with the same problem: [shim](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim) plugin can solve most of issues with [compatibility 2.x and 3.x version](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/tree/master/docs).